# recv call using gevent

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent

I had to perform multiple function calls simultaneously by doing

```
gevent.spawn(recv)
```

So if in one recv(spawn), one function is waiting for response,other recv spawn thread started but making it blocking in execution for the second function

```
def recv(*args, **kwargs):                                             
    while 1:                                                           
        try:                                                           
                return client_socket_fd.recv((args[0]))                
       except Exception, e:                                           
                err = e.args[0]                                        
                if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:    
                            sleep(1)                                   
                            print 'No data available'                  
                            continue                                   
                else:                                                  

                            break
```

How can we proceed this?

Comment: There is no thread shown. Read [ask], provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coroutine (gevent uses coroutines not threads), will 'yield' to another coroutine on various calls. This includes calling *the gevent version* of functions such as `sleep`, `recv`.

In order to call the normal socket/IO/timing code and have gevent work correctly, you need to *monkey_patch* this code. This means calling a gevent function which replaces built-in Python modules with its own versions. Typically, you want to run

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

at the very start of your code. This avoids weird bugs where some code has already started to use the vanilla socket or file code, and then the code changes before the operations have completed.

Comment: So by using these monkey patch we can run simultaneous recv calls without getting blocked by another one?i added this monkey patch of code but still i am getting blocked by another recv call.